# The Code is running Only One method and not the second or third one

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a script to automate a website and I want multiple logins so that all of the accounts work is done at the same time but the program is running only the first method. I am using selenium in console application it works but there is some problem.

I have tried searching for it.

```
Main Code File:

using System;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace AdsCheck
{

public class UnitTest1
{




    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://adsjob5k.com/5k02/login.php";

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("bla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("bla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("agree")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("code")).SendKeys("");

        Thread.Sleep(60000);




        driver.Url = "http://adsjob5k.com/5k02/viewads.php";



        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("buttonN")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(40000);
            driver.Navigate().Refresh();

        }
    }

    public void TestMethod2()
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://adsjob5k.com/5k02/login.php";

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("blabla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("blabla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("agree")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("code")).SendKeys("");

        Thread.Sleep(60000);




        driver.Url = "http://adsjob5k.com/5k02/viewads.php";



        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("buttonN")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(40000);
            driver.Navigate().Refresh();

        }
    }
}
}

The Driver File:

using AdsCheck;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
class Driver
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        UnitTest1 unitTest1 = new UnitTest1();

        unitTest1.TestMethod1();
        unitTest1.TestMethod2();
    }
}
}
```

I just want both the methods to work. There are no errors but it is running only the first method.

Comment: How do you know that method 2 is never run? They look like the same method. You should add some print statements and reduce the loop down to a handful in each method so you can see it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Parallel.Invoke(Action[])`

Something like:

```
Parallel.Invoke(unitTest1.method1(), unitTest1.method2())
```

Now, method1 and method2 should execute in parallel so roughly at the same time.

The reason why it seems like method2 is never executed, could be the `thread.sleep(40000)` in method1's for loop. Method2 has to wait 40 * 100 = 4000 seconds for method1 to finish.
Are you sure you need those thread.sleep() methods?

Comment: Yes, I need to wait for 35 or 40 seconds. I now know of this command only if there is another better command so let me know.